# Design pattern in Android (cross platform with xamarin)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to make a quite simple application in multiple devices using xamarin (iOS and Android).

So I read/think that the best way to doing this is to put one folder (shared between all projects) that contains all the:

- DataLayer (for physical storage)
- DataAccessLayer (support data operations)
- ServiceAccesslayout (communicate with an external API)
- BusinessLayer (Application Facade)

And for the view, the applications will use their custom language

So first question, does it sound great?
Second: How add that kind of folder, that should be updated in every project in Visual Studio 2012? Actually I have one solution with two projects and the two projects (iOS and Android) should have that same folter (tat contains all the "core" layers)

By the way if you have already read a tutorial that talk over that question, please give it to me.

Comment: this [sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/the-xamarin-field-service-app-a-cross-platform-starter-kit/) from Xamarin shows one possible way of breaking up a project for multi-platform targeting

Comment: Okay thanks but the projet won't compile :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at MVVMCross, it is a great way of sharing the maximum amount of code across platforms.

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross